# Changing System Property in Java - Security Policy file

Tags: java, security

I have some confusion in understanding Java Security model. In my `${JDK_HOME}/jre/lib/security/java.policy` file, I could see below entries:

```
grant { 
    // Allows any thread to stop itself using the java.lang.Thread.stop()
    // method that takes no argument.
    // Note that this permission is granted by default only to remain
    // backwards compatible.
    // It is strongly recommended that you either remove this permission
    // from this policy file or further restrict it to code sources
    // that you specify, because Thread.stop() is potentially unsafe.
    // See "http://java.sun.com/notes" for more information.
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "stopThread";

    // allows anyone to listen on un-privileged ports
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1024-", "listen";

    // "standard" properies that can be read by anyone


    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";
..... .....
```

The last line that reads: `permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";`

I interpret it as: The Java Program that runs in the VM has permission to read the property **'java.vm.version'**

Following this understanding I wrote a sample program just to check, If I get any run time error If I alter this property:

```
    System.setProperty("java.vm.version", "my.jvm.version.2345");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
```

There was no error; instead the `System.out.println` display my modified value i.e. `my.jvm.version.2345`

Does that mean policies set in `java.policy` is not working, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the java.policy file is not used in a normal java process.  you must first configure the java process to use a SecurityManager (.e.g add "-Djava.security.manager" to the command line).  More details [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html).

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste time messing with policy files.  They are difficult enough for programmers to get right, and virtually impossible for end users.

If an app. needs trust, digitally sign it, and convince the user to trust the code when prompted.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and I too agree with you. I was just curious to see, how the policy file model works?

Comment: @Vicky  I have never messed with policy files enough to tell you!  ;)

Comment: Haha! So you are telling people not to mess with policy files because you don't understand them yourself?