#  Is it possible to have a firewall around applications?

Tags: java, networking, firewall

I want to host a game called Minecraft and let people upload their own Java JAR.
Now I want to restrict them to a certain port range.
As running all JVM's in virtual boxes is overkill we just stack them, but how do I prevent a user of using the default port?
Maybe something with javaagent in startup line?

EDIT:
Would this be a good sample code?
`System.setSecurityManager(...);
// invoke the jar with a URLClassLoader`

Comment: I don't understand the *close* votes as *off topic* - looks like a valid question to me with `SecurityManager` being one of the possible answers...

Comment: @Voters: This is *not* off-topic. Programmatically restricting the app's port-trange is a perfectly on-topic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're actually looking for a sandbox and not a firewall.  The java [security manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) lets you do things like this through policies.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to modify the security policy for the JVM to restrict network access. Some info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html#SocketPermission

Comment: How could I implement that? Will I have to run a JVM that executes a JAR with those permissions? Some sample code would be great!

Comment: @BronzeByte: Read the whole page (or the start of it, at least)

Comment: @BronzeByte - you would put the uploaded jar files in a particular folder, and set permissions on that location as the 'codebase'. The policy file already exists in the JVM config somewhere - you just edit it. There is example config and info at the top of the page I linked.

Comment: @BronzeByte - no :) You don't need code. There is already an xml file containing the policy that is part of the JRE configuration, which you just need to edit.

Comment: @sje397 I can't seem to find the file path in any documentations :P

Comment: Some info: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.security/usepolicy.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667118/changing-system-property-in-java-security-policy-file - it depends on your OS, and it looks like you can configure the location as well

Answer (score 0):

And what about other security issues like file system access? Looks like you need a VM restricted like an Applet in a browser ([Applet Security Managers](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Security/Fundamentals/Security.html)).

Comment: JVM means Java Virtual Machine, now just need to make it not access the host system :) But I already have an application for not touching other files (not tested yet) and I chmod everything well :)